# Store Lon,Lat in generated column - PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I would like to store lon, lat as varchar in an PostgreSQL generated column that uses the_geom as data source.

```
alter table poi add column 
lonlat varchar generated always as (
st_x(the_geom)|| ', '|| st_y(the_geom)
)
stored;
```

The problem is, that I get the following error:

> ERROR: generation expression is not immutable

Is there another way to archieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volatility of the concatenation operator `||` (as well as the functions `CONCAT|CONCAT_WS`) is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`, as it may invoke datatype formatting functions.

And as per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html)

> - The generation expression can only use immutable functions [...]

---

I can think of two ways:

- use a *[composite type function expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)* as column; instead of the actual column, create a function that (specifically!) accepts the *composite type* of your relation as parameter, and that does the concatenation; for your convenience, name it after your intended column name:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lonlat(rec poi)
    RETURNS TEXT AS
      $$
        SELECT ST_X($1.the_geom) || ', ' || ST_Y($1.the_geom);
      $$
    LANGUAGE SQL
  ;
  ```

  Use it like a *relation qualified* column:

  ```
  SELECT *, poi.lonlat
  FROM   poi
  ;
  ```

  **This is *very fast*, easy, versatile, and the functional expression is perfectly indexable.**
- create an `IMMUTABLE` function wrapper using the `CONCAT` *C* function:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat(VARIADIC TEXT[])
    RETURNS TEXT AS
      'text_concat'
    LANGUAGE INTERNAL
    IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
  ;
  ```

  and create your table with it:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE poi
    ADD COLUMN lonlat TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 
      IMMUTABLE_CONCAT(ST_X(the_geom), ', ', ST_Y(the_geom))
    ) STORED
  ;
  ```

  **Those core functions are `STABLE` for a reason.** For anything but `TEXT` (or implicitly cast `VARCHAR`) this wrapper may silently fail, or break things like indexes; I added the explicit type to the parameter to avoid this as much as possible.

  **Use only for this specific purpose.**

---

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372666/create-an-immutable-clone-of-concat-ws/54384767#54384767
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369

Answer (score 2):

You can only have immutable functions in a generated field. The problem here is not the ST_X or ST_Y function, but the concatenation. For wathever reason, concatenation in postgresql is stable and not immutable. You can see the definition of a function doing this:

```
select pg_get_functiondef('concat'::regproc)
```

The simplest way to do what you want should be by creating a concatenation function which is immutable, by doing this (you need top priviledges to do this so you probably need to login as postgres to your db):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat(VARIADIC "any")
RETURNS text AS 'text_concat'
LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE;
```

Then you should be able to do this (untested):

```
ALTER TBALE poi ADD COLUMN
lonlat varchar GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    immutable_concat(ST_X(the_geom), ', ', ST_Y(the_geom))
)
stored;
```

You should use this immutable version carefully tho, because it can apparently change the output depending of the type of argument in input, especially with date (see for exemple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372666/create-an-immutable-clone-of-concat-ws). This function is originally not immutable for a reason. But in your case there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried the function from geozelot. Since the function uses

```
immutable_concat(VARIADIC TEXT[])
```

I had just to do an typecast to ::text to make it work:

```
ALTER TABLE poi
  ADD COLUMN lonlat TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 
    IMMUTABLE_CONCAT(ST_X(the_geom)::text, ', ', ST_Y(the_geom)::text)
  ) STORED
;
```

With the propose from robin loche using:

```
immutable_concat(VARIADIC "any")
```

it works without typecast.

Comment: This post popped up today again; the reason for my functon to *not* accept the generic `ANY` type is the volatility concerns you can read about in the linked posts. The function accepting only `TEXT` makes it safe for all purposes, while moving type casts into the function leaves it vulnerable for volatile type transformations.